# N15 Pulsar Crank Angle Sensor replacement

Tags: nissan, pulsar, crank-position-sensor

My wife has a 1999 Nissan Pulsar (N15) which lost power and died a few days ago. It was towed by the RAC to a workshop which diagnosed the Crank Angle Sensor.

The estimated cost to fix is AU$700, which I am questioning but have not been able to find much information to support or discredit this estimate.

Does anyone have experience with the CAS in the Nissan N15 Pulsars?

Where is it located and how long does it take to remove it?

Comment: Is that with the SR20DE engine? And it is FWD? If so, it looks like the engine is an incredibly tight fit in the engine bay.

Comment: From what I'm seeing on other Nissan models of the same year, it looks as though the sensor is located on the transmission end of the engine, on the backside of the engine (side closest to the firewall). This would place it under the intake manifold/throttle body area. If so, I can see why it would be a true PITB.

Comment: What is the engine size? Does the Pulsar have a European version name?

Comment: I believe it is the SR 2.0 Litre engine, FWD. I tried to look around through some service manuals etc and called a few mechanics but didn't get any definite answer as to where it is/how hard it is to replace. One mechanic suggested 2-3 hours labour might be about right...

Comment: I think Almera is the European name for Pulsar

Comment: @Paulster2  You answered this in your comments.  I googled it and found the same.  Can you respond with your comment as an answer?  TY.  If you post in the closed votes cafe, zaid can upvote it in order to close it out.

Comment: I have a 99 Nissan Almera and the crank angle sensor is integrated into the distributor.  If it goes bad you have to change out the whole distributor which is pretty expensive.